# Trying to identify release version of an application reading a xml file using shell script

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep, cut

Trying to identify release version of application reading an xml file.

file : /u01/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml

```
grep -Po '(?<=VER=)[^ ]*' /u01/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml |head -1 |sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
11.13.17.08.0
```

Another version

```
grep -Po '(?<=VER=)[^ ]*' /u01/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml |head -1 |sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//
11.12.0.0.0
```

this is how it is being used in the script (code snippet)

```
REL_VER=`grep -Po '(?<=VER=)[^ ]*' /u01/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml |head -1 |sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`
if [[ $REL_VER =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0]{1,}$ ]];  then
    echo "Identified as Release 13" | tee -a ${OUT_FILE}
    ${ROOT}/r13patch.sh >>${OUT_FILE} 2>&1
else
    echo "Not a Release 13 Skipping Patching" | tee -a ${OUT_FILE}
```

In some cases it is exactly detecting the version and the install scripts are starting but in some cases it is not eg: 11.12.1.0.0

Request experts helps to refine the variable matching part in the script so that 11.13.17.08.0 and any other combination of 11.13.x.x.x has to be identified as Release 13 and all other has to be taken as different release. for example any values similar to 11.11.x.x.x or 11.12.x.x.x or 11.10.x.x.x 12.11.x.x.x should go to "Not a Release 13 Skipping Patching" in the script.

Thanks for your answers

Used the same way with cut, but forget to update here,

```
REV_FILE1=/u01/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml
REV_FILE2=/u01/APPLTOP/app/inventory/ContentsXML/comps.xml  
if [ -f ${REV_FILE1} ]; then
REL_VER=`grep -Po '(?<=VER=)[^ ]*' ${REV_FILE1} |head -1 |sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'|cut -d"." -f1-2`
elif [ -f ${REV_FILE2} ]; then
REL_VER=`grep -Po '(?<=VER=)[^ ]*' ${REV_FILE2} |head -1 |sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'|cut -d"." -f1-2`
else
   log_warn "Unable to identify release version"
fi
if [[ ! -z ${REL_VER} && ${REL_VER} == 11.13 ]];  then
    log_info "Identified as R13"
    ${ROOT}/r13patch.sh >>${OUT_FILE} 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        log_info "R13 APP Patching finished successfully"
    else
        log_crit "R13 APP Patching failed"
    fi
else
    log_info "Not a Release 13 Skipping Patching"
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant contents of this xml file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file that's actually complete enough to read with a real XML parser (so answers could built that use xmlstarlet, xmllint, xsltproc, and other command-line tools that *actually understand XML*)?

Comment: BTW -- all-caps variable names are used for shell and environment variables *with meaning to the shell itself, or to POSIX-defined tools*. The POSIX standard reserves lowercase names for application use, so scripts can use lowercase names without worrying about modifying shell behavior by accident; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing of the XML file is, as they say, courageous. It might work because you know how it is created, but it is also irrelevant for the question.

```
version=$(echo REL_VER| cut-d. -f1)
release=$(echo REL_VER| cut-d. -f2)
#etcetera
```

will give you the different fields in your version number.

Comment: Used the same way with cut, but forget to update here,

Comment: @charles-duffy thanks for the answers/suggestions. Used the same way with cut, but forget to update here, New code snippet  updated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's insufficient information in the question to allow the parsing to be helped, but how best to identify the version once it's parsed out from the file is easy enough: Use a `case` statement.

```
case $version in
  11.13.*) echo "Release 13; proceeding" >&2 ;;
  *)       echo "Release not from 11.13.x series; aborting"; exit 1;;
esac
```